# Backward compatibility in Windows Mobile Version

Tags: windows-mobile, windows-mobile-6.5

Will an application developed for Windows Mobile 6.5 run on a Windows Mobile 6.1 device?

Comment: It depends if the application uses/requires specific features from Windows Mobile 6.5.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use windows mobile 6.5 code and applications directly within mobile 6.1. There are only some API functions in WEH 6.5.3 that are not part of WM6.1.

A problem can be the redesign of the screen between 6.1 and 6.5: the start icon is now at bottom and the menu is built of tiles. The bottom menu area is larger than in 6.1. That will give problems with screen size, if the app is designed with hard coded window sizes.

The SHFullScreen API does not work in 6.5 as in 6.1 (see my blog hjgode.de/wp).

But in general, the applications will run without probs.

Josef